# Vba excel: invisibility if data in cells

Tags: excel, vba

I am dumping data from one sheet to another using vba code .All cells are getting correctly populated except 6 cells in the beginning.Actually the data us populated in these cells but its not visible until I double click on the cells.What is going wrong.Can someone help?

Comment: A friend told that the format of the cells is differing.How can I paste the format of one cell in which it is working fine to this cell?

Comment: **Help us to help you; post your current code.**

Comment: Hey I just got my code working.Thanks :)

Comment: The formatting of cells was differing actually.

Comment: Then you should either delete the question, or reply yourself and mark your answer as the answer, in order to close the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are blaming the wrong format you have two options:

a) clear the format of the destination cells, e.g. `Worksheets("DestinationSheet").Range("A1:A6").ClearFormats` and then copy the data without formatting

b) copy the format from some cell whose format is correct, e.g. `Worksheets("DestinationSheet").Range("B1").Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A6")` and then copy the data without formatting (this means you copy good format but wrong data first, but then in the next action you are going to overwrite the wrong data with good data)

Note 1: to copy the data without formatting it is better to use direct assignment `Worksheets("DestinationSheet").Range("A1:A61").Value = Worksheets("SourceSheet").Range("A1:A6").Value` than Copy function

Note 2: In my view it is always better to avoid using Copy & Paste in two commands because you are messing with the system clipboard, which it dangerous at least. Just imagine the user wants to use the clipboard in another program at the same time you are running the macro in Excel... To my best knowledge, the Copy function above (without being followed by Paste) does not use the system clipboard (please someone do correct me if I am wrong)